# Line tool in Flash CS3 appears jagged

Tags: flash, cs3

Can anyone help me? I us Flash CS3 a lot to draw, and usually, as it should be, the line tool draws a clean vector line. But sometimes when I use this tool the line appears jagged, as if it were a bitmap. What's happening? Did I accidentally hit a keystroke that changes one state to the other?

Answer (score 2):

You likely changed the type of line you're drawing accidentally. Check the properties window at the bottom of the screen. There's a drop down with a picture of the type of line you're drawing. Some of them are jagged.

Another thing to check is here: Go under View > Preview Mode and set it to Anti-Alias Text. Some of the other modes will cause it to look fuzzy or even pixelated. Full is the best overall setting. Pay attention to the shortcut keys you see in that list. You may have hit one of them causing your problem.